# Oracle BLOB insert no KB

Tags: vb.net, image, oracle, insert, blob

Here is the code I'm using, it inserts a BLOB but the image once downloaded is 0KB.  Can't figure out how to read all this in properly.

```
        Dim temp As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Dim FileStream As Stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead((temp))
        Dim array() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(temp)

        Using memory As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(array)
            Using reader As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(memory)

                STSQL = "insert into mpcs.image_resource"
                STSQL = STSQL & " ("
                STSQL = STSQL & "IMAGE_TYPE,"
                STSQL = STSQL & "IMAGE_NAME,"
                STSQL = STSQL & "IR_ID,"
                STSQL = STSQL & "IMAGE,"
                STSQL = STSQL & "APP_NAME,"
                STSQL = STSQL & "SIZE_BYTES,"
                STSQL = STSQL & "APP_NAME_TCAT"
                STSQL = STSQL & ") values ("
                STSQL = STSQL & "'image/jpg'," 'IMAGE_TYPE
                STSQL = STSQL & "'" & Label40.Text & "'," 'IMAGE_NAME
                STSQL = STSQL & "MPCS.IMAGE_RESOURCE_PK_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL," 'IR_ID
                STSQL = STSQL & "'" & reader.ReadByte & "'," 'IMAGE
                STSQL = STSQL & "'SHOP_INV',"  'APP_NAME
                STSQL = STSQL & "'" & FileStream.Length & "'," 'Size Bytes
                STSQL = STSQL & "'IR_APP_NAME'"  'APP_NAME_TCAT
                STSQL = STSQL & ")"
```

Ok here's my latest attempt after learning some more, I don't know if any of this works but so far I'm getting a missing expression on this one and I don't know where its at.

```
Dim fs As New System.IO.FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
Dim b(fs.Length() - 1) As Byte
fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length)
fs.Close()

Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO mpcs.image_resource (IMAGE, IMAGE_TYPE, IMAGE_NAME, SIZE_BYTES, IR_ID) VALUES (@IMAGE, @TYPE, @NAME, @SIZE, @IRID)"

Using Conn As New OleDbConnection(Private)
    Using CMD As New OleDbCommand()
        With CMD
            .Connection = Conn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = query
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMAGE", OleDbType.Binary).Value = b
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@TYPE", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "image/jpg"
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Label40.Text
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@SIZE", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = b.Length
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@IRID", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = "MPCS.IMAGE_RESOURCE_PK_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL"
        End With
        Try
            Conn.Open()
            CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error Message")
        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316887

Comment: I can't seem to plug in my own details into that and make the above work.  This is the first time I've insert a blob, sorry, still learning.

Comment: Updated the OP with my latest attempt, hopefully I'm closer to wrapping this up.

Comment: Appreciate any direction anyone can point me in.  Really want to learn what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Anyone at all, willing to try anything here.